# Save togglebutton state in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton, custom-adapter

I had been searching about how to save the state of the togglebutton in a custom listview. I have a listview with a custom adapter which have a text, togglebutton and an imageview,the idea is when toggles the button the imageview changes to show a bulb ON and I need to save the state of which bulbs are ON and OFF.

Here is my code:

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import Adapters.MenuLucesAdapter;
import Adapters.MenuLucesDimAdapter;

public class MenuLuces extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_luces);

        ListView list1, list2;

        String[] iluminacionGrupos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.iluminacion_Grupos);
        String[] iluminacionNombres = {
                "Nombre 1",
                "Nombre 2",
                "Nombre 3",
                "Nombre 4",
                "Nombre 5",
                "Nombre 6",
        };
        String[] iluminacionDimNombres = {
                "Nombre Luz Dimeada",
                "Nombre Dim",
                "Nombre Dim",
                "Nombre Dim",
                "Nombre Dim",
                "Nombre Dim",
        };
        Boolean bulbState = false;
        Integer bulbDim = 0;
        // Array of booleans to store toggle button status
        boolean[] estadolamparasonoff = { false, false, false, false, false ,false };


        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            estadolamparasonoff = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("estadolamparasonoff");
        }

        //**************** ListView1*****************//

        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        MenuLucesAdapter adapter = new MenuLucesAdapter(this, iluminacionGrupos, iluminacionNombres, bulbState);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);


        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.i("MenuLuces", "Item seleccionado " + position);

                if (position == 0) {
                    //Intent menuLucesIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuLuces.class);
                    //startActivity(menuLucesIntent);
                }

            }

        });

    //**************** ListView2*****************//

        list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView2);
        MenuLucesDimAdapter adapterdim = new MenuLucesDimAdapter(this, iluminacionGrupos, iluminacionDimNombres, bulbDim);
        list2.setAdapter(adapterdim);


        list2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("MenuLucesDim", "Item seleccionado " + position);

                // Dependiendo de la posicion creamos un Intent para abrir la Activity correspondiente
                if (position == 0) {
                    //Intent menuLucesIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuLuces.class);
                    //startActivity(menuLucesIntent);
                }

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
package Adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;



public class MenuLucesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] iluminacionGrupos;   
    private final String[] iluminacionNombres;  
    boolean [] switchState = new boolean[100]; //
    private final Boolean bulbState;            

    public MenuLucesAdapter(Activity context,
    String[] iluminacionGrupos, String[] iluminacionNombres, Boolean bulbState) {
        super(context, R.layout.menu_luces_listview, iluminacionGrupos);
        this.context = context;
        this.iluminacionGrupos = iluminacionGrupos;
        this.iluminacionNombres = iluminacionNombres;
        this.bulbState = bulbState;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtGrupo;
        TextView txtNombre;
        ImageView estadoBulbo;
        ToggleButton botonlamp;
    }


    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    //Se asocia el Layout con el Listview customizado para cada item de la lista segun la variable position
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //---print the index of the row to examine---
        Log.d("Luces ON/OFF",String.valueOf(position));
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_luces_listview, null, true);

            //---get a reference to all the views on the xml layout---
            holder.txtGrupo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_LucesGrupo);
            holder.txtNombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_LucesNombre);
            holder.estadoBulbo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_Bulb);
            holder.botonlamp = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_LucesOnOff);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        holder.botonlamp.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("toggleButton"+position, false));  //default is false

        //---customize the content of each row based on position---
        holder.txtGrupo.setText(iluminacionGrupos[position]);
        holder.txtNombre.setText(iluminacionNombres[position]);

/*
        holder.botonlamp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    //int index =  (Integer) v.getTag();
                    //Log.i("tag of switch==",""+index);
*/

        holder.botonlamp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleButton"+position, holder.botonlamp.isChecked());
                editor.commit();

                    if(holder.botonlamp.isChecked())
                    {
                        holder.estadoBulbo.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_led_on);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        holder.estadoBulbo.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_led_off);

                    }
                }
            });

        /*
            if(switchState[position])
                holder.estadoBulbo.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_led_on);
            else
                holder.estadoBulbo.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulb_led_off);
        */

            holder.botonlamp.setTag(new Integer(position));

            return v;
    }

    @Override

    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

}
```

I have two problems:
1.-When the toggle button is clicked the corresponding image is not changed accordingly, only the last row of the listview changes the image. 
2.-When I return to the previous activity the state of the toggle buttons is restored to the default state.